# String search for a unicode start heading character in MongoDB

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have a basic document that looks like this in a collection named pcat:

```
{
    name: "asdf \u0001 fdsa"
}
```

\u0001 is a unicode char for starting a heading, http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0001/index.htm, and it got in here by mistake.

I need to find all the documents in my collection that have this character in them, however I'm unable to write a query to match these.. have tried with:

```
> db.pcat.find({name: /\u0001/}).pretty()
> 
> db.pcat.find({name: /\\u0001/}).pretty()
>
```

But I'm not competent enough to manage to write a matching search string. Is there some special way to find these type of chars inside MongoDB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to do it with `$regex`:

```
db.pcat.find( { name: { $regex: "\u0001" } } )
```